# How can I use regex to find series of data within a text file?

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file with a series as follows:

```
Lots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots
 of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of
 textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of
 textLots of text

Wave amplitude (mean, 3.0 & 7.0 above LES) (mmHg)
43-152
35.9
N/A
N/A
N/A
43.5
21.9
N/A
37.3
N/A
40.9
N/A

    Wave duration (mean at 3.0 & 7.0 above LES) (sec)
2.7-5.4
2.5
N/A
N/A
N/A
2.2
3.0
N/A
2.2
N/A
2.6
N/A

    Onset velocity (between 11.0 & 3.0 above LES) (cm/s)
2.8-6.3
2.2
N/A
N/A
N/A
2.5
1.0
N/A
2.5
N/A
2.7
N/A

Some other textSome other textSome other textSome other textSome other textSome
 other textSome other textSome other textSome other textSome other textSome 
other textSome other textSome other textSome other textSome other textSome 
other text
```

The rules are:

1. The first line always contains a bracket somewhere and this isn't found elsewhere.
2. There is always an empty line at the end of each series of numbers(or series of N/As)
3. The values are all either numbers (with or without decimal points) or N/A.
4. I do not want to capture the first number after the title of each block (which also usually contains a - or <)

I would like to capture the title and the subsequent numbers into one arrayList.

The expected output for the first example would therefore be

```
[Wave amplitude (mean, 3.0 & 7.0 above LES  (mmHg),35.9,N/A,N/A,N/A,43.5,21.9,N/A,37.3,N/A,40.9,N/A]
```

I am stuck on the regex that would allow me to achieve this. Because the text I want to extract lies within a bigger text file I think I need to use regex to extract just the part I'm interested in. I suppose an alternative would be to select out just the start and end of the entire section I'm interested in but it would still rely on some regex and I think the pattern to do this would be more complex.

Comment: Are the number of numbers always the same?

Comment: Why using regex at all? Read it line by line, store everything until an empty line into your array and skip the second line, if you don't want it?

Comment: [Something like this?](https://regex101.com/r/rC8cB8/1)

Comment: Thanks ClasG. What happens if the number of lines is of variable length?

Comment: That is why a regex is not the right choice. Follow advise by @SebastianProske, and just use a simple line-reader, e.g. [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and its [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) method. To quote [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski): *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

Comment: :) If you prefer a harder way, here you are: [`(?:^|\n\n)(.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nH7xY5/1). However, you need to explain why regex is the only choice for you *inside the question body*.

Comment: @SebastianZeki (First - remember to include the "@user" or they, or in this case, I, won't get notification ;) I have to agree with the other comments - why use regex for it? I can see benefits with using regex in many cases where people *yell* - "Don't use regex for that". But this isn't one of them. Go with Proskes recommendation.

Comment: Hi @ClasG. Its the fact that the pattern lies within other text. I've amended the question.

Comment: Bear in mind that using regex will force you to load all that "Lots of textLots of text..." into memory. Also, this doesn't hinder you from using @SebastianProske method - just scan to the first empty line, then start reading into the array.

Comment: So you only want the first block of data as an array (as per your desired result)? Or do you really want an array of those - one array for each data block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to use regex for parsing this, you can do like this:

```
String pattern = "(?<desc>.*\\(.*\\).*)\n.*-.*\n(?<data>(?:N/A\n|\\d*\\.\\d*\n)+)";

String rawData = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("indata.txt")));
Matcher seriesMatcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(rawData);
while(seriesMatcher.find()) {
    List<String> series = new ArrayList<>();
    series.add(seriesMatcher.group("desc").trim());
    series.addAll(asList(seriesMatcher.group("data").split("\n")));
    System.out.println(series);
}
```

The regexp consist of several parts:

```
(?<desc>.*\\(.*\\).*)\n.*-.*\n(?<data>(?:N/A\n|\\d*\\.\\d*\n)+)
--------------------- ------- ---------------------------------
description           ignore  data
```

`description` = A line containing a matched pair of parenthesis. 
`ignore` = An line with a dash, to be ignored. 
`data` = The entries, ie any number of lines either `N/A` or a decimal number.

Comment: TO be fair to me that's pretty much what I did before you posted it but seeing as you're the poster you get the points.